# Scrapy doesn't download pictures

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to download pictures from different urls via scrapy. I'm new to python and scrapy so maybe I'm missing something obvious. This is my first post on stack overflow. Help would be really appreciated!

Here are my different files :

items.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
class PicscrapyItem(scrapy.Item):
image_urls = scrapy.Field()
images = scrapy.Field()
```

pipelines.py

```
class PicscrapyPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for url in item['image_urls']:
        if re.match(r'https', url):
            yield Request(url)

def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
    if not isinstance(request, Request):
        url = request
    else:
        url = request.url
    image_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(url)).hexdigest()  # change to request.url after deprecation
    return '%s.jpg' % image_guid
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'picScrapy'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['picScrapy.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'picScrapy.spiders'
DEPTH_LIMIT = 3
IMAGES_STORE = 'F:/00'
IMAGES_MIN_WIDTH = 500
IMAGES_MIN_HEIGHT = 500
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
LOG_FILE = "log"
```

pic.py

```
from urlparse import urljoin
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from picScrapy.items import PicscrapyItem


class PicSpider(Spider):
    name = "pic"  # 定义爬虫名
    start_url = 'https://s.taobao.com'  # 爬虫入口
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                  '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36',
    }

def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(1, 2):
        # url = 'http://www.win4000.com/wallpaper_2285_0_10_%d.html' % i
        url = 'https://s.taobao.com/list?spm=a217f.8051907.312344.1.353deac38xy87V&q=' \
              '%E8%BF%9E%E8%A1%A3%E8%A3%99&style=' \
              'grid&seller_type=taobao&cps=yes&cat=51108009&bcoffset=12&s='+str(60*i)
        yield Request(url, headers=self.headers)

def parse(self, response):
    item = PicscrapyItem()
    item['image_urls'] = response.xpath('//img/@data-src').extract()
    yield item

    all_urls = response.xpath('//img/@src').extract()
    for url in all_urls:
        url = urljoin(self.start_url, url)
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

log

```
2017-07-11 14:28:25 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: picScrapy)
2017-07-11 14:28:25 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings:     {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'picScrapy.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES':     ['picScrapy.spiders'], 'LOG_FILE': 'log', 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 3, 'BOT_NAME':     'picScrapy'}
2017-07-11 14:28:25 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-07-11 14:28:25 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-07-11 14:28:25 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-07-11 14:28:25 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['picScrapy.pipelines.PicscrapyPipeline']
2017-07-11 14:28:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-07-11 14:28:25 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-07-11 14:28:25 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-07-11 14:28:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET    https://s.taobao.com/list?   spm=a217f.8051907.312344.1.353deac38xy87V&q=%E8%BF%9E%E8%A1%A3%E8%A3%99&style=gr    id&seller_type=taobao&cps=yes&cat=51108009&bcoffset=12&s=60> (referer: None)
2017-07-11 14:28:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200         https://s.taobao.com/list?    spm=a217f.8051907.312344.1.353deac38xy87V&q=%E8%BF%9E%E8%A1%A3%E8%A3%99&style=gr    id&seller_type=taobao&cps=yes&cat=51108009&bcoffset=12&s=60>
{'image_urls': [], 'images': []}
2017-07-11 14:28:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-07-11 14:28:26 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 426,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 37638,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 11, 6, 28, 26, 395000),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 11, 6, 28, 25, 778000)}
2017-07-11 14:28:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable a **pipeline** in your **settings.py** file. If you want to use the **scrapy pipeline**, add this to your settings:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
```

If you want to use a custom pipeline (like the one in your **pipelines.py**) you can add it in your settings:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'[directory].pipelines.PicscrapyPipeline': 1}
```

where [directory] is the directory where your **pipelines.py** file is

Comment: thanks，those are big problems i didn't find, but there are still something wrong after i add them ( T ~ T)

Comment: Thanks so much for that hint with the correct [directory]!